# Difficulty creating ForeignKey constraint in Django

Tags: django, django-3.0

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    campaign_name = models.TextField()    

class SessionLog(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    campaign_name = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ERROR FROM WEBSITE:

> OperationalError at /admin/session/sessionlog/ (1054, "Unknown column
>   'session_log.campaign_name_id' in 'field list'")

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO: create a drop-down list on `SessionLog` to populate campaign_name based on entries in Campaign. I am new to asking questions. Please be kind if I have explained myself wrong.

I have been trying to learn myself. I have read and reread and looked and browsed StackOverflow and then read some more when pointed in this direction: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships

I tried the first answer given, which led me to trying various other things as well. In the end, I keep seeing this via the website:

```
ignored_wrapper_args    
(False,
 {'connection': <django.db.backends.mysql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f5d3768ec88>,
  'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7f5d375a5240>})
params  
()
self    
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7f5d375a5240>
sql 
('SELECT `session_log`.`id`, `session_log`.`date`, '
 '`session_log`.`campaign_name_id`,
```

Towards the end, you see it keeps trying to find campaign_name_id .. which does not exist. I can't find anywhere where I've said to find it.

And when I double-check my `sessionlog` database table is set up correctly, I see this via `MySQL`

```
mysql> describe session_log;
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date                | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| campaign_name       | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| chapter_name        | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| scene_name          | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| character_name      | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location_name       | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| npc_name            | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| monster_name        | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| item_name           | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loot_pp             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loot_gp             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loot_ep             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loot_sp             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loot_cp             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session_xp          | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session_strongstart | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session_secrets     | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session_clues       | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session_notes       | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    campaign_name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.campaign_name    

class SessionLog(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    campaign_name = models.ForeignKey("appname.Campaign", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Replace appname with your Django application name. I hope this might help you with your problem.. And have you registered your model in the `admins.py` file.

I'm not clear whether you are getting an error in retrieving the data from the database or monitoring on the admin page.

Comment: I get the error when I view the webpage admin-side, which is what I'm trying to learn how to configure.

Comment: Then add python manage.py makemigrations app name then python manage.py migrate

Comment: I did the make migrations, migrate. No change on the error. My apologies, I am still new; however, I took on the daunting task of having two databases (default & intaverna) for my first huge project that's not a tutorial. I edited my original post, as well.

Comment: usually django will create a id as a model field , even without defining it in the model. Try without mentioning it. or over write the name of "id as campaign_name_id" which is actually searched

Comment: @Drezna check in the migrations folder for last updated py file 'name like this 0001.auto......py'. check for fields what it is written there...

Comment: My apologies. It's been a long day of work. Here is the latest migrations: ```class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Campaign',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('campaign_name', models.TextField()),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'campaign',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),```

Comment: This is a brand new install. I accidentally broke the entire thing and started completely fresh. I just finally got to this point and same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not made the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I had removed the id index, thinking that I was supposed to because django creates its own. Well, that caused a lot of errors.

I rebuilt from scratch, made sure my db setup had id and index and a few foreign keys set up and wala! All better. :) The did the appropriate makemigration and migrate steps. :)

Thank you for all your pointers in the right direction!